# How to keep Javascript custom dropdown/popover and similar interactions open while styling it?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, browser-sync

I'm taking Javascript dropdown as an example in my question but it's for every interaction which appears on hover and we need to activate them each time again after page refresh

I want to edit the style in my editor of a custom JS dropdown which is quite down in the page (below the fold on my browser, my machine) and see the live preview while I make any HTML and CSS change and press Ctrl+S , Is there a way to keep it open?

The example of the dropdown is here http://jsfiddle.net/Zf3m7/1599/ it usages Bootstrap 3.0.0 JS and CSS as a base.

HTML

```
<p id='container'>
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-large' data-popover="true" data-html=true data-content="<a href='http://www.wojt.eu' target='blank' >click me, I'll try not to disappear</a><br>
```

http://www.wojt.eu' target='blank' >click me, I'll try not to disappear
http://www.wojt.eu' target='blank' >click me, I'll try not to disappear">hover here

JS

```
var originalLeave = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave;
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave = function(obj){
  var self = obj instanceof this.constructor ?
    obj : $(obj.currentTarget)[this.type](this.getDelegateOptions()).data('bs.' + this.type)
  var container, timeout;

  originalLeave.call(this, obj);

  if(obj.currentTarget) {
    container = $(obj.currentTarget).siblings('.popover')
    timeout = self.timeout;
    container.one('mouseenter', function(){
      //We entered the actual popover – call off the dogs
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      //Let's monitor popover content instead
      container.one('mouseleave', function(){
        $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave.call(self, self);
      });
    })
  }
};


$('body').popover({ selector: '[data-popover]', trigger: 'click hover', placement: 'auto', delay: {show: 50, hide: 400}});
```

CSS

```
#container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 8em 3em;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what a JS dropdown is, but if it is just a regular dropdown then you can grab or give the dropdown a class name and then write this if you have jQuery: $('.CLASSNAME').click()

Answer (score 0):

Based on your gulpfile, which is almost verbatim what's on the [BrowserSync + Gulp page](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp#gulp-sass-css), when you save a scss file gulp watch should trigger your `sass` task which pipes to `browserSync.stream()`. This will tell browsersync to inject the new CSS without reloading. However, your HTML changes must trigger a reload and your `html` watcher reflects this.

If you want your dropdown to always remain open even if you manually refresh the browser, you should try opening it and right click to `inspect element` and see what class it adds in order to always remain open. You can then tell a script to always apply that class on page load. Just don't forget to remove the class before sending it to production.

Comment: In the current setup, I can't edit JS as it's CDN link of the JS library.

Comment: You wouldn't edit the javascript from your CDN, you could create a `<script></script>` tag in your HTML to house the code that adds the class. You could write the script inline or have it load an external `.js` file to  do this.